# Why is the characteristic function of a probability distribution function uniformly continuous?

Tags: probability-theory

Why is the characteristic function of a probability distribution function uniformly continuous? This is from page151 of Chung's A Course in Probability Theory.

Specifically, why is the last inequality true?
$|\phi(t+u)-\phi(t)|=\left|\int (e^{i(t+u)x}-e^{itx})dF(x)\right|\leq\int |e^{iux}-1|dF(x)$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland my question is about one step in the proof of that post that is not explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have that

$$\left| \int (e^{i(t+u)x} - e^{itx}) dF(x) \right|  \leq \int \left| e^{i(t+u)x} - e^{itx}\right| dF(x) $$

Then you use the fact that

$$ \left| e^{i(t+u)x} - e^{itx}\right| = \left| e^{itx}( e^{iux} - 1) \right| = \left| e^{itx} \right| \left|  e^{iux} - 1 \right|$$

Then you remark that $\left| e^{itx} \right| = 1$, so

$$\left| \int (e^{i(t+u)x} - e^{itx}) dF(x) \right|  \leq \int \left| e^{i(t+u)x} - e^{itx}\right| dF(x) = \int \left| e^{iux}-1 \right| dF(x)$$